# Anchor Links Stop Working After Changing Body Style in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have run into a problem today that I have not seen anywhere else.

It only occurs in IE 11.  FireFox, Chrome and Safari work fine on Mac OSX, iOS and Windows.

I have a large page full of links.  Lets say, 2000 pixels tall.

My browser window is only 500 pixels tall.

When I display a Modal, I set the height: 500px; and overflow: hidden; on the body element so that the page content cannot scroll.  After the modal is closed, I delete the height and overflow properties from the body tag's style attribute (with jQuery) so the page can be scrolled again.

The problem is, after the modal is closed, none of the links will work below the window height (those outside of the visible area of the browser window, between 501px and 2000px down the page).  Putting your mouse over the link shows no visual change to the mouse pointer or the link text, and clicking on the link does nothing.  The links that were in the visible are of the browser window continue to function normally.

It's bizarre and I don't know how to work around it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: when you right click and inspect said links with the developer tools, what comes up in them? It's possible that something might be positioned over them and thus preventing you from clicking them (it's a long shot, but without a live example, or code to reproduce the issue its difficult to say much else)

Comment: IE is not as kind as other browsers when it comes to invalid markup, does your html validate?  http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @StephenKC I am an engineer on the Internet Explorer team and would be happy to look into this for you. Do you have a repro, or some code you can share?

Comment: Sean, I thought the same thing. Inspecting the link takes me to the link. There doesn't appear to be anything sitting over the anchor.

Comment: @JonathanSampson The URL is http://www.hallmark.com/offers/?searchkey=offers.  Just click on "Find a Store" or "Watch the Video", then close the modal. You will see that links in the visible area are clickable, and links that were not in the visible window are not clickable anymore.

Comment: @StephenKC Thank you, I see the issue you're referring to. Opening the developer tools, or tabbing to a link, both appear to resolve the issue, so this may be a problem with the browser itself. Investigating further.